# Servlet.service() for servlet [ServletAdaptor] in context with path [] threw exception - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I am hosting a Jersey RESTful service on tomcat, which deploys without any error. However when I send a request to the web service it throws the below error.

```
INFO: Server startup in 4950 ms
Jul 28, 2015 5:59:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ServletAdaptor] in context with path [/MyStayWebServices] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.Annotated.getRawType()Ljava/lang/Class;
    at org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.findSerializer(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:428)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.findSerializer(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector$Pair.findSerializer(AnnotationIntrospector.java:664)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.findSerializerFromAnnotation(BasicSerializerFactory.java:385)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.findBeanSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:99)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:486)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createAndCacheSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:456)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:336)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:257)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:692)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.writeTo(JacksonJsonProvider.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Below is the list of libraries included in the project.

[image]

The jackson-mapper.jar has the method getRawType(),
[image]

```
However server complains java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.Annotated.getRawType()
```

Please suggest how can I fix this issue.

Comment: Make sure you don't have another version of Jackson already in your server. NoSuchMethodError usually means conflicting versions of the same jar on the classpath

Comment: @peeskillet thank you, I just have 1.9.2 version of jackson jars. 

Here are the list of jackson jars - `jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar, 
jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar, jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar, jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar` 

And Jersey jars - `jersey-client-1.18.jar, jersey-common-2.0-m05.jar, jersey-container-servlet-core-2.0-m12-1-sources.jar, jersey-core-1.18.jar, jersey-json-1.18.jar, jersey-multipart-1.18.jar, jersey-server-1.18.jar, jersey-servlet-1.18.jar`